# local intranet sites breaks internal dns

Tags: windows, group-policy, internal-dns

Setting the Site to Zone Assignment List in domain group policy breaks access to intranet DNS resources.

Details:
We have an existing Windows domain with very little in the way of Group Policy set. There are two domain servers and each is also a DNS server.

A workstation has the two DNS servers set statically.

PrimaryDns Suffix: mydomain.local

Everything is working fine.

Then, we add two entries to the Site to Zone Assignment List in group policy. Ex:

```
name: http://*.mydomain.local value: 1
name: file://*.mydomain.local value: 1
```

When the workstation updates with this group policy suddenly DNS lookups for internal resources do not work.

Ex: ping myserver.mydomain.local returns a not found error

Attempting to browse to an internal website (any browser) does not work.

DNS lookup of external resources continues to work.

We've tried enabling: Automatically detect intranet network

We've tried adding entries like the following:

```
name: mydomainserver.mydomain.local value: 1
name: mydomainserver value: 1
```

Adding the domain server to the hosts file mysteriously still fails a ping.

Disabling the Site to Zone Assignment List, and leaving/re-joining the domain (because group policy will no longer update), fixes the issue.

It seems as if access to internal resources by name (access by IP works fine) is actively blocked once this policy object is created.

I've search and search to no avail. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `mydomain.local` also your Windows Domain name? If so I would expect assigning it to an IE Security Zone may have unexpected results. At the very least, I wouldn't try to assign it to any zone other than Trusted Sites (2). Also remember that you should **not** add any A-records to your AD integrated DNS servers for your Windows Domain name, since that will impair the functioning of the Domain. The automatically generated A records are necessary and adding other A records will "poison" the round-robin resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS zone (mydomain.local) should have an A record for the intranet.

So, let's say myserver.mydomain.local is 192.168.1.10.

What happens if you run an nslookup on myserver.mydomain.local?  Is it using the local DNS server?

You should be able to PING that by host name and IP before and after any group policy changes.

You should also be able to PING just "myserver" using the NETBIOS name.

We do this with intranet sites and Active Directory/DNS all the time.

If you can't establish connectivity with it, the browser or GP portion won't work.

I will add your GPO to our domain and see if it breaks us too.

Comment: DNS zones has an A record for the domain controller/dns server as well as one for the zone (same as parent folder).

Comment: (hit enter too early)
DNS zones has an A record for the domain controller/dns server as well as one for the zone (same as parent folder).

nslookup pre-GPO, it is using the local DNS controller. I need to try this after GPO.

I can ping *before* the change by host name, fqdn, and ip

After the GPO ping by ip works, does not work by fqdn, and I believe it does by host name alone (netbios) but I have to retest

Also, ping -a by ip returns the correct name after the GPO

Thanks

Comment: Do you need and have host headers setup on the Intranet site that may prevent http://myserver.mydomain.com vs http://myserver or http://192.168.1.10?  That is in bindings.

Comment: I am pushing the trusted sites zone list through via a Registry key (HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\) - I am getting the applied policy on my PC (our Intranet server is in Trusted Sites now) and I am able to access via IE.

Comment: Try creating a new GPO using the registry key method - I have no idea why a GPO for IE would break DNS.  Here is an example: 
 http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2012/07/how-to-configuring-ie-site-zone-mapping-using-group-policy-without-locking-out-the-user/

Comment: I just discovered that this has nothing to do with the GPO. This issue with DNS lookups of local IPs exactly coincided with the new GPO...until it didn't.

I just had it occur again and haven't touched the GPO.

Something is breaking the DNS for local IPs on a single workstation, when it is sitting here doing nothing. Off to investigate...